# Sonar Qube plugin Failed to install on Mule Studio

Tags: sonarqube, mule-studio

I tried to install sonar qube plugin from http://downloads.sonarsource.com/eclipse/eclipse/ in Mule Studio Version (3.5.0)  with Mule runtime (3.4.0). For my requirement I cannot got with the latest version of studio.

The following is the error message I am getting when trying to install the plugin in Mule studio

The operation cannot be completed.  See the details.
Details:
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: SonarQube Integration for Eclipse 3.5.0.20150804-1512-RELEASE (org.sonar.ide.eclipse.feature.feature.group 3.5.0.20150804-1512-RELEASE)

Answer (score 0):

I tried installing the Sonar Qube plugin from the Eclipse marketplace, SonarQube 3.5.0 was listed there, but it was also mentioned that it has been deprecated and SonarLint 1.1.0 should be used instead.

[image]

I went ahead with the installation but as you reported it couldn't be completed as there seems to be a problem with the SonarQube Integration for Eclipse component.

However, can you try creating an offline copy of the update site and then try installing the plugin in studio?

http://mcuoneclipse.com/2014/07/03/replicating-an-eclipse-update-site-for-offline-usage/

**EDIT**

I continued with the same SonarQube installation, it took a lot of time and eclipse had to look for various alternate solutions (15 in total), but it finally came up with this dialog.

[image]

So, while installing the plugin, unselect the 2 components (if you don't need it) and move ahead with installation, I was able to successfully complete it, eclipse restarted and it was all done.

-Shanky G.